# I am not a chef - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.
Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.
Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.
The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.
Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.
We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.
Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,
Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.
Two types of clues to guess one type of me.
What on the earth could I possibly be?

Hint 1:

> Two types of clues implies that there are literal and wordplay clues.

Hint 2:

> The wordplay begins early. Some clues are for a single letter, others for a string of them.

Hint 3:

> Chances are very high you have one, but that you can't see it and you never will.

Comment: Hopefully a higher quality question than my first of the day.

Comment: Come on, Aggie - I already figured that hint out :) I'm pretty sure I know what lines 3 and 4 mean, I just can't patch them up with the stuff around it.

Comment: I have an idea which nobody's tried yet. Short on time now, but I'll post it later on tonight.

Comment: Would I be right to say lines 4-6 (and maybe 3) are wordplay? Or don't you want to give that away yet?

Comment: They are, and maybe more are.

Comment: Though one line plays the role of both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is the answer a

> pancreas?

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> As a direct clue, the pancreas is an organ in the digestive system that is involved with processing cooked stuff, i.e. food.
>  Wordplay-wise, a "PAN" is used for cooking. The other clues clue the remaining letters.

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> "C" is a homophone, as clued by "discuss", of sea = ocean

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> "R" comes alphabetically between Quizzes and Sandwiches

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> "E" is the first letter of "eating"

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> "A" makes up half of the letters of "area".

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> "S" is the most common letter to make English nouns plural and makes you wonder if "pancreas" is a plural; it's not.

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,

> Well, the organ is pretty small compared to other organs in our body, I guess.

Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.
Two types of clues to guess one type of me.
What on the earth could I possibly be?

Comment: Very nicely done. As a note, the pancrease is around the size of your thumb, and is close to the same size across all body sizes. Very well done!

Comment: Way more complex than I have imagine.  Nice riddle and answer!

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Table salt?

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> We need salt for cooking

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> Water in Ocean contains salt; the more it has the harder you can sink in it

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> Quizzes on a table, salt on a sandwiches

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> You add some table salt before you start eating

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> We use half a table to eat? (this guess is weak)

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> A table salt bottle has many salt

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,

> Salt is tiny

Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> It is referring to the 'table'

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.

> Clue on Table and Clue on Salt

What on the earth could I possibly be?

> Table Salt!

Comment: I like it. Not what I was looking for, but I really like it. Very clever.

Comment: Thanks but I guess I am not even close!  Give me some time =)

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> a stomach?

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> The current state of your stomach (full, empty, partially full) directly affects what you want to cook.

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> the stomach is sort of like an ocean, with its stomach acid? Also sometimes people feel a sinking feeling in their stomach.

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> butterflies in your stomach from a quiz, full stomach after eating a sandwich.

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> Before you eat, you're the most hungry.

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> Stomachs can expand to twice their size as you eat more.

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> Often people joke about having a second stomach for desserts.

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,

> Stomachs are only about the size of a fist.

Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> Height doesn't affect stomach size.

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.

> Honestly not sure about this one.

What on the earth could I possibly be?

> A stomach

Comment: Incredibly close. I'm rather impressed. But not quite. Check out the hint.

Comment: Ooooh, I think I know what it is! What's the policy for editing my guess? Do I edit this post and leave the old one, or do I just overwrite it with my second guess?

Comment: I've seen both. Not sure what the most accepted practice is. If you do edit this one, Put a header over this section and just append your new answer to the beginning.

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. Looks like someone else already guessed it.

Comment: For future reference, when you edit a post, there's a link that appears at the bottom of the post with a timestamp of when the edit occured. Clicking on the link will show the edit history of that post. That way people can edit to their heart's content and still be able to track who technically answered first.

Answer (score 2):

Second attempt (original below):

> Ears

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> Ears of corn? Also cooking does make noise, especially frying or sauteing

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> You can hear the ocean in your ears

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> your brain (which handles quizzes) is sandwiched between your ears

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.
Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.
We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> These three lines are the wordplay. "e" is the beginning of eating. "ar" is half of area, and we add an "s" to make it more than one. Still not sure about the "feast" part

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,
Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> Like my previous rationale, ears are small no matter what your height (though some people do have smaller/larger ears)

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.
What on the earth could I possibly be?

--- ORIGINAL GUESS ---
Here's an answer:

> eyes

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> If food looks good it can have an effect on our appetite and desire to eat it

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> Haven't gotten this line yet

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> Your eyes are between your brain (quizzes) and sandwiches (mouth)

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> This gives you an "e", also your eyes can "feast" on a view

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> Area is x*y, so "y" is half of it (this part's shaky)

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> "eyes" is a homonym for "I's" - are "I's" more than one person?

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,
Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> Eyes are a small part of the body, no matter your height

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.
What on the earth could I possibly be?

> We have the wordplay ones and the literal clues

Comment: Close! You've got hint 4 (mostly).

Comment: Second try - think it's slightly better

Comment: Another good try! I'll give you the hint that feast isn't that important.

Comment: I'm just going to keep guessing body parts. Eyebrows! Toes! Belly Button!

Comment: Is it floaters? 'cause that was the answer to another puzzle from a few days ago.

Comment: Nope. I haven't seen this as an answer, and really doubt it would have been one.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is the word

> EAT.

### Metaphor lines

*I have more to do with cooking than you might think.*

> Well, obviously! After food has been cooked, it gets eaten.

*Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.*

> Could be a reference to washing up in the *sink* after eating?

*Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.*

> This could be a very clever piece of wordplay that I haven't worked out.

### Wordplay lines

*The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.*

> The beginning of "eating" is the letter **E**.

*Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.*

> Half of the letters in "area" are **A**s.

Now how many words are there relevant to cookery that begin with the letters

> EA?

Right, so we have the answer. The next line is **very** clever...

*We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.*

> "Wrap up" is a crossword-style clue that tells us we're looking for an anagram. EAT is an anagram of ATE, which is a homophone of EIGHT, which is indeed "more than one".

*Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,*

> The word "eat" is quite small, only three letters.

### Last lines

*Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.*

> You can eat no matter what your height may be.

*Two types of clues to guess one type of me.*

> The metaphor and wordplay sections of the riddle - see above.

*What on the earth could I possibly be?*

> The letters E, A, T are contained in the word "earth"!

Comment: You give me far too much credit. I love the thoughts, but this isn't it. Great job though.

Comment: @AggieKidd Could it be HEART then?

Comment: Not that either.

Answer (score 1):

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> Water? Heat?

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> Water

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> and?

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> eat?  As in (h)eat?

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> also (h)ea(t)

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> heat and water?

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,

> water molecules are small. heat is VERY small.

Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> nope it doesn't....

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.

> Water - steam ice?

What on the earth could I possibly be?

> I say:  steam

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but great try!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's

> a nose!

I have more to do with cooking than you might think.

> The nose plays a huge role in eating and cooking affecting our appetite.

Now let us discuss the ocean, try not to sink.

> Not quite sure, maybe an advice to people who tend to take nose-picking to the extreme.

Then between quizzes and sandwiches I like to rest.

> Like someone else already figured out: the nose lies between the brain (quiz) and the mouth (sandwich).

The beginning of eating, a feast is the best.

> Many people begin eating with smelling the food.

Half the area is needed, we aren't quite done.

> We only use one nostril at a time.

We wrap up wondering if I am more than one.

> Maybe because we have two separate nostrils... not sure about this one.

Now as you guess, know that I am quite small,
Doesn't really matter if you are short or tall.

> Noses can be any size not matter how tall you are.

Two types of clues to guess one type of me.

> That's already in the hints.

What on the earth could I possibly be?

> A nose!

Comment: Oh well, I did not consider the wordplay part of the riddle. So it's maybe not the answer...

Comment: Definitely a nice try, but as you pointed out, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> forearm

Phone is out of battery will post rationale la---